# Solving a trigonometric equation for purely imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm puzzled with the following exercise:

"By constraining $z$ to be purely imaginary, show that the equation $\cos{(z)}=  2$ can be represented as a standard quadratic equation. Solve this equation for $z$."

Any tips or ideas on how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use $\cos z = \frac {e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that by [Euler’s formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$$

Comment: Thanks. However, I got stucked because the resulting expression is not a standard quadratic equation (maybe I miss something). Let $z=i b$, with $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{-b}+e^{b}}{2} = 2$. I do not know how to follow now...

Comment: Assuming $z=iy$ we obtain $e^{iz}=e^{-y}$ and $e^{-iz}=e^{y}$. Then let $t =e^{y}$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: Your way is fine, now multiply both side by $e^b$ and obtain a quadratic equation in $e^b$ as unknown.

Comment: Now I see! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

W.K.T $$\cos(x) = \left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right)/2$$
So,    $$\cos(z) = \left(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}\right)/2 = 2$$
$$ \left(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}\right) = 4$$
$$ e^{2iz} +1 = 4e^{iz}$$
$$ y^2-4y+1=0$$
where $$ y= e^{iz}$$
which is a quadratic
$$y=\left(\frac{4\pm\sqrt {16-4}}{2}\right)$$
$$e^{iz}=\left(\frac{4\pm\sqrt {16-4}}{2}\right)$$
$$=2\pm \sqrt3$$
$$iz= \ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$$
$$z=-\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)i$$

Comment: It can be simplified to $\ln(2\mp\sqrt3)i$.